# Raspberry Pi stream video over RF

Tags: python, radio

I would like to stream video from a Raspberry Pi over RF to another Raspberry Pi. Here are a few requirements:

- Range of at least 1KM (pretty much line of sight)
- I would also like to send some data along with the stream - or simply another packet (would just be a couple of sensor readings)
- It needs to work across the land, ie not a HAB - I saw somewhere that there was a zone when transmitting across the land?
- The video stream needs to be of high enough quality to be able to see it, 720p would be ideal but I understand that that is a lot of data
- Ideally the two Pi programs can be written in Python
- power is an issue, although not a major one so low powered is good!
- the streaming Pi would be moving (within the 1km range) and the other Pi would be stationary

I am in the UK and know that for 2.4GHz and 5.8GHz you don't need a licence, is that correct?

Is what I am asking possible and feasible? I don't want to spend too much money and am looking for a DIY solution.

I've been testing some NRF24l01 + PA+LNA modules, one with an external antennae and one without, but am getting really bad ranges (5m - line of sight), I am running them at a datarate of 250KBPS and at the maximum PA. I was wondering if anyone could shed any light on this too? Ideally, I would like to use them for the above project.

Comment: Why not just high power WIFI adapters with directional antennas?

Comment: So the Pis would be connected to the same WiFi network? Would this one be ok: http://www.zead.co.uk/default.asp?page=14 The Pi that is streaming the video is moving though so directional antennas might be a problem.

Comment: You can either set up an ad hoc connection between them or have one RPi be an access point. No need for another wifi base station.  I can't suggest any adapters that are sure to work with the RPi

Comment: What about the fact that the streaming Pi is moving?

Comment: @developius movment only becomes an issue if the transmitter moves out of range of the receiver, assuming you don't use a directional antenna. RF is luckily omni-directional by nature. Distance isn't the only factor that can affect signal quality. Geography and EM interference can drastically affect transmission distances.